# How to create a floating point variable in LANSA

Tags: lang

I have something like this

```
Define Field(#FLTPOINT) Type(*DEC) Length(7) Decimals(0)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to define it in RDML or RDMLX. How do I create a floating point variable in LANSA?

(Actually, are there any LANSA developers out there? I'd never heard of it until I started at this job!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DEFINE will create a fixed length decimal. To create a floating point use;

```
Define Field(#FLTPOINT) Type(*FLOAT)
```